# Explicit instantiation of template function before definition

Tags: c++, c++11

Are explicit instantiations of template functions allowed before the definition of the function, if a declaration occurs first?

E.g., is the following allowed:

```
// declaration
template <typename T>
void foo(T param);

// explicit instantiation
template void foo<int>(int);

// definition of primary template
template <typename T>
void foo(T param) {}
```

In general it seems to compile, but of course that is only a mild indication as to whether it is allowed or not.

Comment: I just had a code where the instantiation was before the definition. It compiled with gcc, but clang refused it.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing that explicitly forbids it in [[temp.explicit]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit). Furthermore, there is an explicit statement ([[temp.explicit#5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#5)):

> A declaration of a function template, a variable template, a member function or static data member of a class template, or a member function template of a class or class template shall precede an explicit instantiation of that entity.

If a definition was required, this paragraph would be different (i.e., it will require a definition), thus your code seems legal.

Comment: The note in that paragraph is pertinent too (despite not being normative).

Comment: @StoryTeller Which note are you referring to?

Comment: The definition is not required to appear before the explicit template instantiation definition, but it is required to appear somewhere in the translation unit.